# Combining columns from the same sections of a form

Tags: sql, sql-server

I was tasked to find out what is possible to be output to excel from forms that are filled out. What I am thinking to do is make one row for each form but the problem is the way the form is input in the database. This is how the the database looks when I try to output all columns from one of the sections(History of Present Illness) of one of the forms: https://i.stack.imgur.com/rtlNK.jpg it looks like it contains other programming languages aside from sql as well. This what the form looks like originally when filled out: https://i.stack.imgur.com/2QY2d.jpg

Right now I tried converting the Text columns to be formatted into varchar using a previous code I used before with the help of another user from here but it is not working correctly for this case.

```
SET ANSI_WARNINGS ON

Select A.IDEncounter_Note
      ,FormatMessage = ltrim(rtrim(replace(replace(replace(TxtOnly,' ','†‡'),'‡†',''),'†‡',' ')))
 From  Encounter_Note A
 Cross Apply ( values ( --replace(
                        replace(
                        replace(
                        replace(
                        replace(
                        replace('<div>'+CONVERT(VARCHAR(MAX),Text)+'</div>'
                        ,char(13),' ')
                        ,char(10),' ') 
                        ,'&'+'nbsp;',' ')
                        ,'&'+'amp;','&')
                        ,'&'+'rsquo;','''')
                        --,'<o:p></o:p>','')-- May want to add items like — as -  and ™ as TM etc...
                      ) 
              ) B(CleanString)
 Cross Apply (
                Select TxtOnly = stuff((Select ' ' +RetVal 
                                         From  (
                                                Select RetSeq 
                                                      ,RetVal = left(RetVal,charindex('<',RetVal+RetVal)-1)
                                                 From  (
                                                        Select RetSeq = row_number() over (order by 1/0)
                                                              ,RetVal = ltrim(rtrim(B.i.value('(./text())[1]', 'varchar(max)')))
                                                        From  ( values (cast('<x>' + replace((Select replace(CleanString,'>','§§Split§§') as [*] For XML Path('')),'§§Split§§','</x><x>')+'</x>' as xml).query('.'))) as A(x)
                                                        Cross Apply x.nodes('x') AS B(i)
                                                       ) C1
                                                Where charindex('<',RetVal)>1
                                               ) C2
                                         Order By RetSeq
                                         For XML Path(''),TYPE).value('(./text())[1]','varchar(max)')
                                        ,1,1,'') 
             ) C
WHERE EncounterID = 89617
```

What I am trying to do right now is make one column for each  section of the form. For example Chief Complaint is one column, and History of Present Columns is another(So I have to combine the 'text' column from the 1st imgur).

Comment: Slight detour but an article you should read. https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-table-aliases-like-a-b-c-or-t1-t2-t3

Comment: For the question at hand I would suggest you check out [this article](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). Follow the advice and we can help.